# Kotlin Java streams - map Selenium WebElement(s) to List

Tags: selenium, kotlin, stream

I'm struggling a bit with a pretty simple case of mapping a list of Selenium WebElements to a List of classes using Java Streams.

The element:

```
val elements: List<WebElement> = element.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-selector=expense]"))
```

(Currently, there are only two elements in the list.)

I'm currently mapping the WebElement list to a MutableList of classes the "classic way":

```
val expenseElements: MutableList<ExpenseElement> = ArrayList()

for (element in elements) {
    expenseElements += ExpenseElement(element)
}
```

Which is working fine. But I feel I should learn to use Stram() to do this more "elegantly". Or, at least, because I want to :-)

But my feeble attempt at using Stream()

```
val expenseElements = elements.stream().map { UtgiftElement(element) }.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

results in only the first element being included. So the first elements takes up both places in the the list.

The first method:

```
expenseElements[0].expense() = "Entry 1"
expenseElements[1].expense() = "Entry 2"
```

The non-working Stream() method:

```
expenseElements[0].expense() = "Entry 1"
expenseElements[1].expense() = "Entry 1"
```

This is basic I know, but I've tried replicating code that does the same in Java. I have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mistake in your mapping lambda. You do:

*map { UtgiftElement(**element**) }*

But that is not correct. The map function provides you with a single input, named `it` by default. Your lambda should either by `map { UtgiftElement(it) }` or `map { element -> UtgiftElement(element) }`.

I do not know where your *element* variable comes from, but I think it is not one of the elements in the stream.

Comment: You're right, of course. The element is the WebEelement the UtgiftElement objects are created from. This works beautifully :-)